# Converting nested JSON of unequal lengths to data-frame in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a JSON file 'data.json' which contains information about different places of interest.

```
data = lapply(readLines("data.json"), fromJSON)
```

This creates a nested list having different lengths. Here's a sample of the first 4 lines.

```
list(structure(list(payload = structure(list(existence_full = 1L, 
    geo_virtual = "[\"56.9459720|-2.1971226|20|within_50m|4\"]", 
    latitude = "56.945972", locality = "Stonehaven", `_records_touched` = "{\"crawl\":8,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}", 
    address = "The Lodge, Dunottar", email = "dunnottarcastle@btconnect.com", 
    existence_ml = 0.569423821765872, domain_aggregate = "", 
    name = "Dunnottar Castle", search_tags = c("Dunnottar Castle Aberdeenshire", 
    "Dunotter Castle"), admin_region = "Scotland", existence = 1L, 
    category_labels = structure(c("Landmarks", "Buildings and Structures"
    ), .Dim = 1:2), post_town = "Stonehaven", region = "Kincardineshire", 
    review_count = "719", geocode_level = "within_50m", tel = "01569 762173", 
    placerank = 65L, longitude = "-2.197123", placerank_ml = 37.2791607346447, 
    fax = "01330 860325", category_ids_text_search = "", website = "http://www.dunnottarcastle.co.uk", 
    status = "1", geocode_confidence = "20", postcode = "AB39 2TL", 
    category_ids = 108L, country = "gb", `_geocode_quality` = "4"), .Names = c("existence_full", 
"geo_virtual", "latitude", "locality", "_records_touched", "address", 
"email", "existence_ml", "domain_aggregate", "name", "search_tags", 
"admin_region", "existence", "category_labels", "post_town", 
"region", "review_count", "geocode_level", "tel", "placerank", 
"longitude", "placerank_ml", "fax", "category_ids_text_search", 
"website", "status", "geocode_confidence", "postcode", "category_ids", 
"country", "_geocode_quality")), uuid = "3867aaf3-12ab-434f-b12b-5d627b3359c3"), .Names = c("payload", 
"uuid")), structure(list(payload = structure(list(existence_full = 1L, 
    geo_virtual = "[\"56.237480|-5.073578|20|within_50m|4\"]", 
    latitude = "56.237480", locality = "Inveraray", `_records_touched` = "{\"crawl\":11,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}", 
    address = "Cherry Park", email = "enquiries@inveraray-castle.com", 
    longitude = "-5.073578", domain_aggregate = "", name = "Inveraray Castle", 
    admin_region = "Scotland", search_tags = c("Inveraray Castle Tea Room", 
    "Inverary Castle"), existence = 1L, category_labels = structure(c("Social", 
    "Food and Dining", "Restaurants"), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)), region = "Argyll", 
    review_count = "532", geocode_level = "within_50m", tel = "01499 302203", 
    placerank = 67L, post_town = "Inveraray", placerank_ml = 41.1997808735227, 
    fax = "01499 302421", category_ids_text_search = "", website = "http://www.inveraray-castle.com", 
    status = "1", geocode_confidence = "20", postcode = "PA32 8XE", 
    category_ids = 347L, country = "gb", `_geocode_quality` = "4", 
    existence_ml = 0.791488110284778), .Names = c("existence_full", 
"geo_virtual", "latitude", "locality", "_records_touched", "address", 
"email", "longitude", "domain_aggregate", "name", "admin_region", 
"search_tags", "existence", "category_labels", "region", "review_count", 
"geocode_level", "tel", "placerank", "post_town", "placerank_ml", 
"fax", "category_ids_text_search", "website", "status", "geocode_confidence", 
"postcode", "category_ids", "country", "_geocode_quality", "existence_ml"
)), uuid = "8278ab80-2cd1-4dbd-9685-0d0036b681eb"), .Names = c("payload", 
"uuid")), structure(list(payload = structure(list(existence_full = 1L, 
    geo_virtual = "[\"51.483872|-0.606820|100|rooftop|2\"]", 
    latitude = "51.483872", locality = "Windsor Castle", hours_display = "Mon-Sat 11:30 AM-11:00 PM; Sun 12:00 PM-11:00 PM", 
    `_records_touched` = "{\"crawl\":7,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":2,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}", 
    address = "", longitude = "-0.606820", domain_aggregate = "", 
    name = "Windsor Castle", admin_region = "England", search_tags = c("The Windsor Castle", 
    "The Windsor Castle Pub", "The Windsor Castle Public House", 
    "Pub Food", "British"), existence = 1L, category_labels = structure(c("Landmarks", 
    "Buildings and Structures"), .Dim = 1:2), region = "Berkshire", 
    review_count = "", geocode_level = "rooftop", tel = "020 7766 7304", 
    placerank = 62L, post_town = "Windsor", placerank_ml = 28.1160845346327, 
    fax = "01753 832290", category_ids_text_search = "", website = "http://www.royalcollection.org.uk/visit/windsorcastle", 
    status = "1", hours = "{\"monday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"tuesday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"wednesday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"thursday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"friday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"saturday\":[[\"11:30\",\"23:00\"]],\"sunday\":[[\"12:00\",\"23:00\"]]}", 
    neighborhood = "Chalvey", geocode_confidence = "100", postcode = "SL4 1NJ", 
    category_ids = 108L, country = "gb", `_geocode_quality` = "2", 
    existence_ml = 0.885705196944165, email = "bookinginfo@royalcollection.org.uk"), .Names = c("existence_full", 
"geo_virtual", "latitude", "locality", "hours_display", "_records_touched", 
"address", "longitude", "domain_aggregate", "name", "admin_region", 
"search_tags", "existence", "category_labels", "region", "review_count", 
"geocode_level", "tel", "placerank", "post_town", "placerank_ml", 
"fax", "category_ids_text_search", "website", "status", "hours", 
"neighborhood", "geocode_confidence", "postcode", "category_ids", 
"country", "_geocode_quality", "existence_ml", "email")), uuid = "c5f7d8a9-0851-46ef-8da7-ad55e187d3a8"), .Names = c("payload", 
"uuid")), structure(list(payload = structure(list(existence_full = 1L, 
    category_ids_text_search = "", placerank_ml = 31.9857184762157, 
    longitude = "-2.191955", name = "Pitmedden Garden", domain_aggregate = "", 
    admin_region = "Scotland", languages = "English", region = "Aberdeenshire", 
    review_count = "2", geocode_level = "rooftop", tel = "01651 842352", 
    placerank = 57L, post_town = "Ellon", category_labels = structure(c("Landmarks", 
    "Gardens"), .Dim = 1:2), existence = 1L, fax = "0844 493 2102", 
    website = "http://www.nts.org.uk/Property/Pitmedden-Garden", 
    status = "1", geocode_confidence = "100", postcode = "AB41 7PD", 
    country = "gb", category_ids = 109L, `_geocode_quality` = "4", 
    existence_ml = 0.849871115334588, email = "information@nts.org.uk", 
    address = "", `_records_touched` = "{\"crawl\":6,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}", 
    locality = "Pitmedden", latitude = "57.343233", geo_virtual = "[\"57.343233|-2.191955|100|rooftop|4\"]"), .Names = c("existence_full", 
"category_ids_text_search", "placerank_ml", "longitude", "name", 
"domain_aggregate", "admin_region", "languages", "region", "review_count", 
"geocode_level", "tel", "placerank", "post_town", "category_labels", 
"existence", "fax", "website", "status", "geocode_confidence", 
"postcode", "country", "category_ids", "_geocode_quality", "existence_ml", 
"email", "address", "_records_touched", "locality", "latitude", 
"geo_virtual")), uuid = "bb57a153-740f-42be-aa4d-ae12d4eb57d4"), .Names = c("payload", 
"uuid")))
```

I want to convert this to a data-frame by populating values across different columns in the list of lists. Each list within the list contains information about a particular place, this is categorized by `uuid`. So each row in the data-frame is going to contain information about a particular `uuid`. For columns that do not have corresponding values, NA should appear.

I tried using some of the approaches mentioned in questions similar to this concept but was unsuccessful.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might have helped to have had a more expansive description of the original data layout but here's a guess, based on what I see as the high level structure of that object. Assume that `structure` is named `dat`.:

```
> lapply(dat, names)
[[1]]
[1] "payload" "uuid"   

[[2]]
[1] "payload" "uuid"   

[[3]]
[1] "payload" "uuid"   

[[4]]
[1] "payload" "uuid"
```

So extract them to lists of dataframes

```
payloads <- lapply(dat, function(x) data.frame(x$payload))
uuids <- lapply(dat, function(x) data.frame(x$uuid))
```

Then bind them "side by side"

```
newdat <- mapply( cbind, payloads, uuids)
```

Then look at the dimensions to see if the single line dataframes get properly copied over tot he multiline dataframes. The one feature that is not to your specifications are the NA's. Since the 'uuids' are apparently identifiers, the `cbind` operations will have copied each of their column contents to columns of the same lengths as the 'payloads':

```
> lapply(payloads, dim)
[[1]]
[1]  2 32

[[2]]
[1]  2 33

[[3]]
[1]  5 35

[[4]]
[1]  1 32

> lapply(uuids, dim)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 1

> lapply( mapply( cbind, payloads, uuids), dim)
[[1]]
[1]  2 33

[[2]]
[1]  2 34

[[3]]
[1]  5 36

[[4]]
[1]  1 33
```

The next level of consolidation might be to assemble all the dataframes "on top of each other since their names are so similar:

```
lapply( newdat, names)
[[1]]
 [1] "existence_full"           "geo_virtual"              "latitude"                
 [4] "locality"                 "X_records_touched"        "address"                 
 [7] "email"                    "existence_ml"             "domain_aggregate"        
[10] "name"                     "search_tags"              "admin_region"            
[13] "existence"                "category_labels.1"        "category_labels.2"       
[16] "post_town"                "region"                   "review_count"            
[19] "geocode_level"            "tel"                      "placerank"               
[22] "longitude"                "placerank_ml"             "fax"                     
[25] "category_ids_text_search" "website"                  "status"                  
[28] "geocode_confidence"       "postcode"                 "category_ids"            
[31] "country"                  "X_geocode_quality"        "x.uuid"                  

[[2]]
 [1] "existence_full"           "geo_virtual"              "latitude"                
 [4] "locality"                 "X_records_touched"        "address"                 
 [7] "email"                    "longitude"                "domain_aggregate"        
[10] "name"                     "admin_region"             "search_tags"             
[13] "existence"                "category_labels.1"        "category_labels.2"       
[16] "category_labels.3"        "region"                   "review_count"            
[19] "geocode_level"            "tel"                      "placerank"               
[22] "post_town"                "placerank_ml"             "fax"                     
[25] "category_ids_text_search" "website"                  "status"                  
[28] "geocode_confidence"       "postcode"                 "category_ids"            
[31] "country"                  "X_geocode_quality"        "existence_ml"            
[34] "x.uuid"                  

[[3]]
 [1] "existence_full"           "geo_virtual"              "latitude"                
 [4] "locality"                 "hours_display"            "X_records_touched"       
 [7] "address"                  "longitude"                "domain_aggregate"        
[10] "name"                     "admin_region"             "search_tags"             
[13] "existence"                "category_labels.1"        "category_labels.2"       
[16] "region"                   "review_count"             "geocode_level"           
[19] "tel"                      "placerank"                "post_town"               
[22] "placerank_ml"             "fax"                      "category_ids_text_search"
[25] "website"                  "status"                   "hours"                   
[28] "neighborhood"             "geocode_confidence"       "postcode"                
[31] "category_ids"             "country"                  "X_geocode_quality"       
[34] "existence_ml"             "email"                    "x.uuid"                  

[[4]]
 [1] "existence_full"           "category_ids_text_search" "placerank_ml"            
 [4] "longitude"                "name"                     "domain_aggregate"        
 [7] "admin_region"             "languages"                "region"                  
[10] "review_count"             "geocode_level"            "tel"                     
[13] "placerank"                "post_town"                "category_labels.1"       
[16] "category_labels.2"        "existence"                "fax"                     
[19] "website"                  "status"                   "geocode_confidence"      
[22] "postcode"                 "country"                  "category_ids"            
[25] "X_geocode_quality"        "existence_ml"             "email"                   
[28] "address"                  "X_records_touched"        "locality"                
[31] "latitude"                 "geo_virtual"              "x.uuid"
```

The `rbind.fill` function in Hadley's `plyr`-package can do this efficiently:

```
install.packages("plyr")
newdat3 <-  do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, newdat)
newdat3
```

So looking at a few of the columns, this appears to have satisfied your requirements:

```
> newdat3[ , c("locality", "category_labels.3", "neighborhood")]
         locality category_labels.3 neighborhood
1      Stonehaven              <NA>         <NA>
2      Stonehaven              <NA>         <NA>
3       Inveraray       Restaurants         <NA>
4       Inveraray       Restaurants         <NA>
5  Windsor Castle              <NA>      Chalvey
6  Windsor Castle              <NA>      Chalvey
7  Windsor Castle              <NA>      Chalvey
8  Windsor Castle              <NA>      Chalvey
9  Windsor Castle              <NA>      Chalvey
10      Pitmedden              <NA>         <NA>
```